# Parse .ics data in an iPhone project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, icalendar, libical

I am making an iPhone application, and I want to use [libical](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libical/) to parse .ics dat from an .ics file *or* from the URL location of the *.ics* file.

Firstly, how would I go about using *libical* in my project? How can I add it into my iPhone project, etc.? I’ve seen some guides, but they seem to be specific to OSX projects and not iPhone projects..

Secondly, how can I parse event names and their descriptions, so that I can store the event names/ descriptions as variables?

Is this possible using libical? If so, roughly how may I go about implementing this?

Comment: Please post the links to the guides you've found.  They should be easily adaptable to iOS development.

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that libical is available under the GPL, which basically means you can't use it in an app that's distributed via the App Store.

Comment: Its mainly for a project at university and i dont think itl get that far.. i think i should probably read up on whether it would be suitable..

Also the link for the guide i mentioned is:
http://confuseddevelopment.blogspot.com/2007/01/shipping-libical-in-mac-application.html

Comment: **i dont think itl get that far *i.e. to the appstore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*.ics* data files are relatively easily parsable. Open one in a text editor and take a look.

I've implemented an ics parser before for exactly what you're trying to do. It took me a couple of hours, and trying to get all sorts of libraries to compile used taken me more in a few occasions :)

Comment: The fact that you replied at all means a lot!!! :)
Could you by any chance maybe direct me to some source code examples?
or would you be able to share some example code from when you did it?
as the purpose is the same i feel the way you went about it may very well be better for me.. As ive spent the best part of a few months trying to make a breakthough with no luck :(

Thank You for anything you can share :)

Comment: I am trying to find how to create the ics file also but don't see how to did you have any luck???

Comment: @brandon's design group open the file with a text editor. The way the events and their metadata are organized in the file are relatively simple to understand. use nsstring stringWithContentsOfFile to read the file. Use NSScanner to parse and extract the data in a loop.

Comment: @brandon's design group not sure what you mean

Comment: In my app I want it to sent an email with the ics attachment. So I have to create it.. How??

Comment: @brandon's design group you might wanna look into mfmailcomposeviewcontroller http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDMQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2FMessageUI%2FReference%2FMFMailComposeViewController_class%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=sAfoTeaiOYr1-gb4_43XDw&usg=AFQjCNEy0N4fIBDa7A5-BSDod2UOrUJqAw&sig2=0Aj8vM1RBnJEO8hxxNNZAg

Comment: It is incomprehensible near *"to compile used taken me more"*.

Answer (score 2):

I found an excellent library for parsing *.ics* files. There are a whole lot of functions too for other tasks, like managing calendar and calendar events.

*[MXLCalendarManager](https://github.com/KiranPanesar/MXLCalendarManager)*