# Swift Convert http response to Data Dictionary

Tags: swift, enums, nsdictionary, icalendar

I am new to Swift, iOS development.

HTTP Request :

```
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

 let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

Response String looks like this

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//MobileUGStdTT//iCal4j 1.0//EN //DateGenerated 06 May 2017 12:05
 :07
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170506T040507Z
DTSTART:20170109T090000
DTEND:20170109T120000
SUMMARY:SG4207 (L)
DESCRIPTION:SG4207-MOBILE WIRELESS SOLUTION DESIGN (LECTURE)
LOCATION:ISS-03-03
UID:20170506T040507Z-MobUGStdTT@fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:fea6:c7e%3
TZID:Asia/Singapore
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER:-PT15M
REPEAT:4
DURATION:PT5M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:SG4207-MOBILE WIRELESS SOLUTION DESIGN (LECTURE) @ ISS-03-03\
 , starts 0900
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20170506T040507Z
DTSTART:20170116T090000
DTEND:20170116T120000
```

I need to convert this response to `NSDataDictionary`/`ENUM`, Since its not a regular `JSON` I am finding it hard to convert it to.

These are the Keys - DTSTART,SUMMARY,DESCRIPTION I am in need of.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The text is in iCalendar (.ics) format which can be parsed with NSScanner or regular expression.

Comment: https://github.com/KiranPanesar/MXLCalendarManager ? from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059554/parse-ics-data-in-iphone-project

Comment: I am trying to use this library via cocoapods, It is giving me a error  "Unable to find the specification" for MXLCalendarManger

Comment: You have to do it your self, you can inspire you with some other works:
https://github.com/kiliankoe/iCal (in Work In Progress) or https://github.com/MasudShuvo/IcsParser/blob/master/IcsParser/Parser/MSCalendarICSParser.m It seems there is nothing all done.

Comment: Thanks @Larme , I figured out a way to parse the ical format. Now I have it as a array of string 
array [0] BEGIN:VCALENDAR

array[1]VERSION:2.0
array[2]CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
array[3]BEGIN:VEVENT
array[4]DTSTAMP:20170506T040507Z
array[5]DTSTART:20170109T090000  and goes on ..... 

Now I need to convert this to class structure. how to pass data to the class via a object